# Jquery select this + class

Tags: jquery

How can I select a class from that object `this`?

```
$(".class").click(function(){
        $("this .subclass").css("visibility","visible");
})
```

I want to select a `$(this+".subclass")`. How can I do this with Jquery?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use [`$(this).find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), or pass this in context, using jQuery [context with selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1).

Using $(this).find()

```
$(".class").click(function(){
     $(this).find(".subclass").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Using `this` in context, `$( selector, context )`, it will internally call find function, so better to use find on first place.

```
$(".class").click(function(){
     $(".subclass", this).css("visibility","visible");
});
```

Comment: If `find()` is being called internally in the second method, why are you still calling it manually?

Answer (score 26):

Maybe something like:
`$(".subclass", this);`

Comment: This is a great alternative. using the context +1

Comment: @Connor This is an alternative but not so great. Anyway +1 too

Comment: I appreciate your opinion @roasted

Comment: @Connor i mainly said that because using context for child selector was supposed to be deprecated: `$('> child',context)`. This was what appear in previous jquery DOC: >>Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.<<  But this disappear from doc and not concern context equivalent to .find(), so... ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff any news on this, is it still safe to use?

Answer (score 12):

Use **[`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
$(this).find(".subclass").css("visibility","visible");
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is this:

```
$(".subclass", this).css("visibility","visible");
```

Add the `this` after the class `$(".subclass", this)`

Comment: This really helped me when trying to animate an SVG for something and find wasn't working how I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

if you need a performance trick use below:

```
$(".yourclass", this);
```

find() method makes a search everytime in selector.

Answer (score 1):

Well using **find** is the best option here

just simply use like this

```
$(".class").click(function(){
        $("this").find('.subclass').css("visibility","visible");
})
```

and if there are many classes with the same name class its always better to give the class name of parent class like this

```
$(".parent .class").click(function(){
            $("this").find('.subclass').css("visibility","visible");
    })
```