# jQuery hover produces error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone see what the issue here is with this small hover code? or maybe there is a better way of writing it?

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Code:

```
$('.animated-banner').hover(
        function() {
            $(this' .faded').removeClass('fade-background');
            $(this' .faded').addClass('fade-transparent');
            $(this' .animated').fadeOut();
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this' .faded').removeClass('fade-transparent');
            $(this' .faded').addClass('fade-background');
            $(this' .animated').fadeIn();
        }
    );
```

Comment: You can not use `this' .faded'`, because you are trying convert DOMelement with string,  try change to  `$('.faded', this).removeClass('fade-background');`

Comment: It's because you're using this' .faded'. I personally don't see why you need to add this seeing as you're already targeting an element.

Comment: I did try that before but get Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement].faded i need to set this and then effect the child class.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, concatenation in javascript is using `+`. Secondly, as Alexander mentioned in the comments, you have to use context with selector like this

```
$('.faded', this).removeClass('fade-background');
```

which is same as

```
$(this).find('.faded').removeClass('fade-background');
```

[Check this answer on SO for more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745927/jquery-select-this-class)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$(this' .faded')`, that is invalid syntax. You could use `$('.faded', this)` if you want to perform queries from this point.

Answer (score 0):

you have invalid selector, `$(this` expecting end of selctor and therefore `)`. If you want to choose from `$(this)` selection only those with some class you have to use additional selecting. Something like

```
$(this).filter('.faded').removeclass...
```

or something similar to this