# Using this with class that contains some special string

Tags: jquery

I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745927/jquery-select-this-class)

But it didnt work if i want to look if that class start by special string.

im trying to achieve something like this

```
   <div   class = "message_holder user12121 chatid47">
```

and when clicking

```
   $(document).on ("mouseenter", ".message_holder", function () {
    this_id = $(this).find("div[class*='user']");
    alert(this_id.replace('user', '')); // i want to alert 12121
    alert(this_id); // tried this also
    })
```

but didnt work . im getting [object OBJECT] error.

if it was a fixed class this could work

```
    $(this).find(".subclass");
```

Comment: `this_id = $(this).find("div[class*='user']");` This returns jquery object, so you can't call `.replace()` on it

Comment: @itsgoingdown check edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add .attr("class")

```js
$(document).on ("mouseenter", ".message_holder", function () {
   var this_id;
  
  var classList = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
  $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
    if (item.indexOf("user") > -1) {this_id = item;}
  });
   alert(this_id.replace('user', ''));
 })
```

```css
.message_holder{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:silver;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message_holder user1235 chat77"></div>
```

**EDIT**
Code has been updated to take into consideration html.

**EDIT 2**
Used an idea from here to create an array of classes.
[Get class list for element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227286/get-class-list-for-element-with-jquery)

Comment: please post the HTML outline, because this example works with the html that was assumed from your jquery.

Comment: this is my outer html `this is my outer html `<div class=" message_holder user45 chatid47"><a class="avatar" title="samir2"> <img height="28px" width="28px" src="/images/vthumbs/6.png"></a><div class="message "> sssss 
            </div><div class="chattime">23 days ago</div><div `

Comment: ok, I see your problem. FIND actually means, FIND as CHILDREN of this object. I updated my code to fix that issue. However, the one last thing that needs to happen is an updated REPLACE.

Comment: Ok , isee that it returns all class names `message_holder 12121` without user . now i will  remove the other names by jquery . It returns all the class . i thought it will return only that id of user

Comment: I needed just this class of user12121 . not all class

Comment: without creating a regular expression that might not take into consideration every variation, I updated my code to create an array of the classes and loop looking for a class with user.

Comment: Thanks that worked :) . i thought there is simple solution with just selecting it directly without looping , but anyway this is what i have right now . thanks so much