# how to make 2 bootstrap sliders in single page without mixing their css and jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

i already built the 2 sliders in different indexes ,, but when trying to make both of them in a single page their CSS and JQUERY will get mixed.........................

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

/* show 3 items */
.carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .active + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item  {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left) + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    transition: none;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.carousel-inner .active.carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -25%;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* left or forward direction */
.active.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
}

/* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}

/* right or prev direction */
.active.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item,
.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item + .carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

this is CSS of Second Slider

```
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
var idx = $e.index();
var itemsPerSlide = 4;
var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
        // append slides to end
        if (e.direction=="left") {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
        else {
            $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
        }
    }
}
```

});

this is JQuery of second slider

only if you tell me how to devide second slider jquery and css from first one its ok

Comment: Try to make a parent class in second slider and use it to write css for the same..

Answer (score 1):

**Learn [how jQuery class selectors work](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).**

In this case you have 2 carousels, and therefore 2 elements with the class `carousel` on the same page. So, `$('.carousel')` can be used to select and handle the `slide.bs.carousel` event on *both* of the carousels.

To determine which carousel instance is being handled, use $(this). [Read more about $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745927/jquery-select-this-class). Then you can **manipulate the CSS for that single carousel instance**.

```
$('.carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

    var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var $t = $(this);
    var $inner = $t.find('.carousel-inner');
    var idx = $e.index();
    var itemsPerSlide = 3;
    var totalItems = $t.find('.carousel-item').length;
    
    if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
        var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
        for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
            // append slides to end
            if (e.direction=="left") {
                $t.find('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo($inner);
            }
            else {
                $t.find('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo($inner);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Please don't copy-and-paste this code without first *understanding* how it works**!

https://codeply.com/go/FiFtXFmt22

---

[Bootstrap carousel multiple frames at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007610/bootstrap-carousel-multiple-frames-at-once/20008623#20008623)

Comment: How can we convert this into vanilla JS? Need something similar for Reactjs hooks without JQuery.